# Twitter bootstrap modal buttons not working when clicked in Selenium

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpath, selenium

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue.  I've got a website utilising twitter bootstrap, at one point in my script I open a modal, I go through and interact fine with several objects within that modal (text input, dropdown, checkbox).  But when I come to clicking the submit button at the end nothing happens.

As far as selenium is concerned it clicked it, and if I watch the screen while its running and could see the button highlight as if clicked, but nothing happens.  If I then try to click on it afterwards still nothing happens other than the button highlights.  If I then hit RETURN or ENTER then it fires fine...

I've tried instead of clicking sending ENTER or RETURN but they all do the same thing and am at a complete loss, I identify the object via XPATH which as far as I can see looks right...

Here's a chunk out of the code, bear in mind that everything before this works...

```
threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='createDeal']").click();

threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[1]/input").clear();
threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[1]/input").sendKeys("MyNewProject");

Select myDropDown = new Select(threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/dl/dd[3]/select")));
myDropDown.selectByVisibleText("Buy Out");

threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ProjectOriginator']/li/input").click();
threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ProjectOriginator']/li/input").sendKeys("John smith");

threadSesh.driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Create')])[2]").click();
```

Its the final line that just does nothing...  Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Also worth pointing out I am using ie and cannot test this in chrome or FF (neither version is allowed on this website I'm testing, its an internal platform).

Another piece of potentially useful information, the button isn't a button in fact but a ref of some kind that's been made to look like a button using the twitter bootstrap stuff, the source for it looks like this: -

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-info" type="button" style="margin-right: 7px; padding-left: 15px; padding-right: 15px;" data-bind="click: ok" href="#">Create</a>
```

If I record it in the seleneium addin for firefox it outputs this: -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//a[contains(text(),'Create')])[2]")).click();
```

Comment: Please include the smallest complete code sample that exhibits your issue.

Comment: Does it work if you add an `id` attribute and use `By.id()`, if only as an experiment if not for your real test?

Comment: @kjhughes I could certainly try switching it over to ID but the object doesn't appear to have one when I look at the source.  Am I being a bit thick?

Comment: I meant by changing the `a` at the source (if you control it) or in a copy to include a unique `id`.  Success (or failure) using `By.id()` may shed light on the problem, which could be IE / XPath related.  Also, if you could try FF or Chrome just for information gathering purposes, that may also help you hone in on the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do either.  I tried another link on the page which is much simpler as I can simply set it to click on link = "cancel" but this doesn't work either :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to come up with a solution to this, only by sheer luck though.  Basically before I click on the Cancel or Create links I was interacting with some tagit inputs and had to do some fiddling to get them to work.

These tagits were in one div (`html/body/div[3]/div[2]`) within the modal and the links were in another (`html/body/div[3]/div[3]`) and this fiddling around seemed to have stopped Selenium from seeing the other div somehow, although I'm not sure how.

To fix the issue I simply added in a click of the modal at the top level (`html/body/div[3]`) and then it found the lower level links fine!  How this fixes it I don't know but at least my scripts work fine again now...

Comment: I've dived into the same problem. I used WebDriver PhantomJS with Python. On the screen there is Bootstrap modal with few tabs in it, on each tab there is the form with multiple fields. When I tried to click() on Bootstrap button, nothing happened and I can't understand why.

Click() became work for me since my code does click()'s on few elements on the form, then on button itself.

Comment: LoL "and this fiddling around seemed to have stopped Selenium from seeing the other div somehow, although I'm not sure how" voted as answer. Thats the worst solution I ever heard of, no offense.

Comment: You don't appear to have understood what was written, that section of text was an explanation to what had caused it to break in the first place...  The final paragraph is how I got round that problem.