# How can I select a value from drop down which is on a Modal-dialog in selenium web driver

Tags: jquery, css, selenium-webdriver, modal-dialog

I am trying to select value from a drop down which is in modal dialog and I am getting following error when I use below selenium code.

I am using FF driver to run my tests

```
Select PrArea = new Select(getCurrentDriver().findElement(By.cssSelector("select#cppractice.form-control")));
    PrArea.selectByVisibleText(PracticeArea);
```

Tests in error:
  Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 50.14 seconds

I have tried Switch to Alert method as well but no luck with that]

```
Alert alert = getCurrentDriver().switchTo().alert();
```

This is the CSS code for the Modal-dialog and the drop down

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<div id="postModal" class="modal-body">
<form id="copyForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<input id="copySrc" type="hidden" value="" name="copySrc"/>
<input type="hidden" value="copyform" name="form"/>
<ul id="_modalTab" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<div id="modalTabContent" class="tab-content">
<div id="_generalTab" class="tab-pane active">
<div id="cptitlegrp" class="form-group">
<div id="cpsourcegrp" class="form-group">
<div id="cpurlgrp" class="form-group">
<div id="servicegrp" class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="service">Practice Area</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select id="cppractice" class="form-control" name="pr">
<option value="252581">*Central</option>
<option value="413561">Agriculture</option>
<option value="131070">Arbitration</option>
<option value="413562">Australia</option>
<option value="413563">Business Crime and Investigations</option>
<option value="413564">Charities</option>
<option value="131707">China</option>
<option value="413565">Commercial</option>
<option value="413566">Competition</option>
<option value="413567">Construction</option>
<option value="242701">Corporate</option>
<option value="413568">Data Protection</option>
<option value="134112">Dispute Resolution</option>
<option value="135082">Employment</option>
```

Any help would much appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using selectByValue?

Comment: If the drop down is on a modal, you'll need to trigger the button / link / action which shows the modal, before you can interact with it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes but still same error. I think problem is drop down is not visible to driver. I feel we need some kind of Switching statement to top window but not sure what should I used here.

Comment: @StuartLC: Could you provide me a sample code how can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at the [first line of this OP's post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20330373/314291) - its as simple as finding the trigger element and clicking on it.